# Why does VSCode not recognize the tilde-quote notation in my CSS file?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code for a pure HTML, JavaScript and CSS project. I imported a CSS file from an old project that was provided to me by a colleague and a few of the lines in the CSS file are marked as having an error in VS Code, such as this one:

```css
.some-class .some-sub-class {
   padding-left: calc(~"50px + .75rem");
}
```

VS Code notes two errors here:

- `) expected` (squiggly line under the tilde)
- `at-rule or selector expected` (squiggly line under the closing bracket)

I was able to determine that both errors were caused by the tilde `~` character, since removing it suppresses the errors, but I need the tilde for those CSS rules.

The file is just a `.css` file if that's relevant, and simply closing it doesn't show any error anymore.

Is there an extension I should add, remove, or configure to make that error go away?

here are the extensions I have installed so far. The issue was happening before I installed any of them:

[image: my currently installed extensions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not valid CSS format, this seems to be `LessCSS`, which means you'd have to select proper filetype: `Less`.
[image]

Comment: Looks like it, I was fiddling around and noticed the extension description was talking about compiling a `.less` file into a `.css` file. I changed it and it seems to work. Thanks.